# Combine Columns in multiple Excel workbooks and auto-de-dupe

Tags: vba, excel

I have three workbooks with IDs in column A. I want to create a fourth workbook, which should combine the IDs and de-dupe them automatically so that I can perform a vlookup on them to reference data on the other workbooks. The 3 workbooks with data in them will be constantly updated with new ID numbers added, so I need the master/summary workbook to automatically grab newly added ID numbers and perform vlookups against the other workbooks.

The goal of this is to give a summary view of each record (which corresponds to a person), letting the user know which workbooks that person exists in.

I have tried doing =max() to retreive the number of ID's in each workbook, and combining them, telling me the total # of ID's that exist, combined. Then I tried to perform this: =SMALL(IF(FREQUENCY(Test1:Test2$A$2:$A$1000, ROW($1:$28))<>0, ROW($1:$28), ""), ROW(A1)) 
+ CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

But I'm 1. not sure if that'll work and 2. not sure how the syntax works with 3 separate workbooks.

I also tried the union method in VBA with no luck - again I think I'm messing up the syntax.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using Excel for this instead of a relational database solution, like Access, or SQLite, or MySQL?  It seems like this would be much easier with a database solution instead of Excel.

Comment: If you need to de-dupe the id's then presumably you have duplicates between (within?) workbooks: that's going to make it tricky to use VLOOKUP...

Comment: No dupes within workbook - an id can and will appear in multiple workbooks though so id like to consolidate the data (columns would be like - "appears in workbook 1?" "Appears in workbook 2?" And I want one row per id. I'll do an access db for this if it's the best route but it's for a temporary data storage solution with 50 users while our database is down so I don't want to put much work into it.

Comment: Are you speaking of workbooks or worksheets? The cell reference Test1:Test2$A$2:$A$1000 used in your sample formula would seem to indicate workSHEETs and not workBOOKs.

Comment: Sorry - it's workbooks. That was in error. I had [workbook1.xlsx]sheet!range in the code I ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve a unique list of the id numbers in [ID_First.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$999 using the following array formula in the master worksheet's A2 (needs a row above it to avoid circular references).

```
=IFERROR(INDEX([ID_First.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$999,MATCH(0, IF(LEN([ID_First.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$999),COUNTIF(A$1:A1,[ID_First.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$999),1),0)),"")
```

If you stack similar formulas consecutively, passing calculation on to them with IFERROR(), you can gain a unique list from three separate workbooks.

```
=IF(LEN(A1),IFERROR(INDEX([ID_First.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$999,MATCH(0, IF(LEN([ID_First.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$999),COUNTIF(A$1:A1,[ID_First.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$999),1),0)),IFERROR(INDEX([ID_Second.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$999,MATCH(0, IF(LEN([ID_Second.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$999),COUNTIF(A$1:A1,[ID_Second.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$999),1),0)),IFERROR(INDEX([ID_Third.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$999,MATCH(0, IF(LEN([ID_Third.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$999),COUNTIF(A$1:A1,[ID_Third.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$999),1),0)),""))),"")
```

Array formulas require Ctrl+Shift+Enter to finalize. Once entered correctly, fill down as necessary to collect all unique IDs.

With a unique list of id numbers, you can use the same method of nested IFERROR functions to look through a series of three workbooks for additional data.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2, [ID_First.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$Z$999, 2, FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2, [ID_Second.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$Z$999, 2, FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2, [ID_Third.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$Z$999, 2, FALSE),"")))
```

I'm offering this as you've mentioned a total of 50 member IDs. This method can quickly (and logrythmically) eat up calculation resources when applied to larger groups of numbers.

Comment: This was super helpful, thanks Jeeped. Thanks for the heads up about the circular reference, too!

Answer (score 0):

If you've got Excel 2016 or later, you could unpivot the data using PowerQuery, which is now built in to Excel under the Get & Transform section of the Data tab in the ribbon. Plenty of examples of how to do this if you search Google for 'unpivot' and 'Powerquery'.

If you have Excel 2010 or 2013, you can download the PowerQuery addin for free from https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=39379 (assuming IT let you do so).

PowerQuery is a revolution in Excel data transformation, and the learning curve is a lot less steep than advanced formulas or VBA.